# Using a custom directive in an ionic modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, directive

I have this **ion-textarea autosize directive**:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]'
})
export class AutoResizeTextareaDirective {
  readonly defaultHeight = 64;

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  onInput(textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
    this.adjust(textArea);
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.adjust();
  }

  adjust(textArea?: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
    textArea = textArea || this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('textarea');

    if (!textArea) {
      return;
    }

    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';
    textArea.style.height =
      (textArea.value ? textArea.scrollHeight : this.defaultHeight) + 'px';
  }
}
```

In my **modal.component.html**:

```
<ion-textarea autosize [(ngModel)]="message.msg_text"></ion-textarea>
```

The directive has been also added to my `app.module.ts`. This doesn't seem to work because I suspect that it's the fact that the field is in a modal. How would I get this to work on a modal as the modal does not contain a `.module.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem was your way to naming, see this example:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor() { }
}

---
<p appHighlight>Highlight me!</p>
```

Your selector I think must be:  `[autosize]` instead of  `'ion-textarea[autosize]'`.

Take a look to: [Angular Attribute Directives Guide](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a solution. Instead of adding the directive to the declarations of `app.module.ts` declare it inside the `module.ts` file of the page you are opening the modal from

Comment: And with you'r old naming woks?